# manage multiples asynctask in an activity what displayed data (Survey App)?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask, survey

i am working for an app(survey App) i need to fill an activity with questions and types of answer(choices, edittext,etc) the questions are in a database in a server(apache-mysql) with web services i get and i can display in an Activity but with the answers i have a problem i call an asynctask but it's display the answer in disorder at activity. I dont know if is the right way is correct using multiples asynctask(to get data of database of some tables).

Please help me i need to correct this in two days

thank you for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fire off a bunch of asyncTasks they run all at the same time so there is no order. If you want to make multiple calls synchronously youll have to follow the pattern from this thread [Pattern to make AsyncTask "procedural"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328013/pattern-to-make-asynctask-procedural)